# Magento 2 - Extend Extension Layouts and Templates

Tags: magento2, layout, extensions, template, extend

Is there a way to extend the layout and template files of an extension?  Say I have an extensions file located at `app/code/<vendor>/<extension/view/frontend/layout` or a file located at `app/code/<vendor>/<extension/view/frontend/templates`, how would I extend/override those files in my own custom theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a directory in your theme directory that matches the desired module, for example `Vendor_Extension`. Inside this directory you make the `layout` and `templates` directories where you put the .xml/.phtml files to be extended/overridden. These files must use the same name as their target file. If the target template file is in a subdirectory, must also duplicate the subdirectory structure.